# Finding the value of the second derivative at an x value? (Implicit Diff)

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

The question is If $xy + 2e^y = 2e$, find the value of $y''$ at the point where $x = 0$.

I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Having, as Dr. Graubner has, $y+ xy'+ 2e^yy'= 0$, I would not solve for y'.  Instead, use "implicit differentiation" again.  $2y'+ xy''+ 2e^y(y')^2+ 2e^y y''= 0$.

$xy+ 2e^y= 2e$, when x= 0, $2e^y= 2e$, $e^y= e$ so y= 1,  Then $y+ xy'+ 2e^yy'= 0$ becomes $1+ 2ey'= 0$, $2ey'= -1$, $y'= -1/(2e)$.  Then $2y'+ xy''+ 2e^y(y')+ 2e^yy''= 0$ becomes $2(-1/(2e)+ 2e^{-1/(2e)}y''= 0$ and $y''= (-1/e)2e^{1/2e}= -e^{1/(2e)- 1}$.

Answer (score 0):

for the first derivative we get
$$y+xy'+2e^yy'=0$$ thus $$y'=-\frac{y}{x+2e^y}$$
can you proceed?
after this we get $$y''=-\frac{y'(x+2e^y)-y(1+2e^yy')}{(x+2e^y)^2}$$
you must insert $$y'=-\frac{y}{x+2e^y}$$
finally we obtain
$$y''=\frac{2e^yy^2}{(2e^y+x)^3}$$
to find $y(0)$ you can plöug in $x=0$ in your first equation:
$e^{y(0)}=e$ thus $y(0)=1$

Comment: The second derivative I get is y'' = -(-2y(2e^y+x)+2e^yy^2)/(2e^y+x)^3   Confused as to what to do next

Comment: you must plug in the first derivative, see my posting

Comment: Oh ok, now i just sub in x = 0 and thats the answer?